# how to make a pageblocktable editable by clicking a radio button

Tags: pageblocktable, radio-button

here i am trying to make a radio button which will when clicked should make my pageblock table editable. is there any way to achieve this, if yes please help me out. here is my vf page--[image]

here is my vf page code--

```
 <apex:selectList value="{!selectedValue}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="1" itemLabel="1"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="2" itemLabel="2"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="3" itemLabel="3"/>
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!search}" rerender="frm"  />
            </apex:selectList>
     records per page

    <apex:inputText value="{!searchstring}" onblur="searchAF();"/>
    <apex:actionfunction action="{!search}" rerender="frm" name="searchAF"/>
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapProductList}" var="accWrap"   >
                    <apex:column >
                      <apex:facet name="header">
                            <apex:inputCheckbox onclick="selectAllCheckboxes(this,'inputId')"/>
                        </apex:facet>
                      <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!accWrap.selected}" id="inputId"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column value="{!accWrap.productObject.PricebookEntry.Name}" />
                    <apex:column value="{!accWrap.productObject.Contract_Start_Date__c}" />
                    <apex:column value="{!accWrap.productObject.Service_Start_Date__c}" />
                    <apex:column value="{!accWrap.productObject.Full_Revenue_Date__c}" />
                    </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

controller--

```
   public void checkSelectedManual(){        
        system.debug('Selected value is: ' + manualRadio);        
    }  
    public void save() {
        update opportunityList;
    }

   ID opportunId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
   public List<Opportunity> opportunityList {get;set;}
    public List<wrapProduct> wrapProductList {get; set;}
    public String extendRadio{get;set;}
    public String copyRadio{get;set;}
    public String manualRadio{get;set;}
    public String selectedValue{get;set;}
    public String searchstring {get;set;}
  public GEN_Op(){ 
   opportunityList = new List<Opportunity>();
   opportunityList = [Select id, Submission_Date__c,Decision_Date__c,CloseDate from Opportunity where id =: opportunId ];
   wrapProductList = new List<wrapProduct>();
   for(OpportunityLineItem priceBookEntryObject: [SELECT PricebookEntry.Name,Contract_Start_Date__c,Service_Start_Date__c,Full_Revenue_Date__c FROM OpportunityLineItem where opportunityId =: opportunId]) {
                 wrapProductList.add(new wrapProduct(priceBookEntryObject));


   }
   }
    public void search(){  
                 wrapProductList = new List<wrapProduct>();
                 string searchquery='SELECT PricebookEntry.Name,Contract_Start_Date__c,Service_Start_Date__c,Full_Revenue_Date__c FROM OpportunityLineItem where PricebookEntry.Name like \'%'+searchstring+'%\' AND opportunityId =: opportunId Limit ' +selectedValue;  

                 for(OpportunityLineItem priceBookEntryObject: Database.query(searchquery)) {
                      wrapProductList.add(new wrapProduct(priceBookEntryObject)); //adding the searched products into list
                 }
        }

        public class wrapProduct {
                public OpportunityLineItem productObject {get; set;}
                public Boolean selected {get; set;}

                public wrapProduct(OpportunityLineItem pBEParam) {
                    productObject = pBEParam;
                    selected = false;
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this will be a lengthy ans so

First take a new boolean variable in wrapper class i.e. `isEditable`

```
public class wrapProduct {
        public OpportunityLineItem productObject {get; set;}
        public Boolean selected {get; set;}
        public isEditable {get;set;}
        public wrapProduct(OpportunityLineItem pBEParam) {
            productObject = pBEParam;
            selected = false;
            isEditable = false;
        }
}
```

You need to add action support on radio button and on click call a controller method.. Here method is i.e `makeeditable`

```
<apex:selectRadio value="{!country}">
        <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" 
                            action="{!makeeditable}" 
                            rerender="pageBlockTableId"/>
</apex:selectRadio>
```

Now in method make isEditable to true..

```
public void makeeditable()
{
    for(wrapProduct objWrapper: wrapProductList)
    {
        objWrapper.isEditable = true;
    }
}
```

and use rendered attribute to display inputField and outpufield based on isEditable boolean

Your Table

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapProductList}" var="accWrap"  Id="pageBlockTableId" >
   <apex:column >
      <apex:facet name="header">
         <apex:inputCheckbox onclick="selectAllCheckboxes(this,'inputId')"/>
      </apex:facet>
      <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!accWrap.selected}" id="inputId"/>
   </apex:column>
   <apex:column  >
      <apex:outputField value="{!accWrap.productObject.PricebookEntry.Name}" rendered="{!!accWrap.isEditable}">
      <apex:inputField value="{!accWrap.productObject.PricebookEntry.Name}" rendered="{!accWrap.isEditable}">
   </apex:column>
   <apex:column  >
      <apex:outputField value="{!accWrap.productObject.Contract_Start_Date__c}" rendered="{!!accWrap.isEditable}">
      <apex:inputField value="{!accWrap.productObject.Contract_Start_Date__c}" rendered="{!accWrap.isEditable}">
   </apex:column>
   <apex:column  >
      <apex:outputField value="{!accWrap.productObject.Service_Start_Date__c}" rendered="{!!accWrap.isEditable}">
      <apex:inputField value="{!accWrap.productObject.Service_Start_Date__c}" rendered="{!accWrap.isEditable}">
   </apex:column>
   <apex:column  >
      <apex:outputField value="{!accWrap.productObject.Full_Revenue_Date__c}" rendered="{!!accWrap.isEditable}">
      <apex:inputField value="{!accWrap.productObject.Full_Revenue_Date__c}" rerender="{!accWrap.isEditable}">
   </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: hii, iam getting this error,,,,,,,--- Unsupported attribute rerender in <apex:outputField> in myVFPage at line 78 column 112

Comment: @RAT__ ohh Sorry ..my mistake this should be `rendered`

Comment: for both input as well as output fields ??

Comment: @RAT__ Yes.. But only one will be displayed at a time based on isEditable value

Comment: ya one more thing i missed to tell , in editable mode checkboxes should be disabled how to achieve that

Comment: @RAT__ which checkbox? manual checkbox above one ?

Comment: those are there in wrapper class , with products

Comment: all of them i have to disabled

Comment: @RAT__ use `disabled` attribute of `apex:inputCheckbox` .. `<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!accWrap.selected}" id="inputId" disabled="{!isEditable}"/>`

Comment: hey if i wants to save it i mean perform update on this wrapper class say, Update wrapProductList; will it save all the updated values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35802/discussion-between-ratan-and-rat).

Comment: @RAT__ No you can't perform DML on wrapper list. INstead iterate over wrapper list and collect all product in new List of product and update those list of product.